# Why wordpress thickbox not really showing for my theme upload option

Tags: wordpress, upload, media, thickbox

I've stuck with this problem for more than 8 hours. I created an option panel for my wordpress theme and add an upload button for the upload logo option. I'm using wordpress thickbox. Everything almost done except the thickbox upload never showing only the thickbox overlay that is showing. I checked the source file and the .js file and stylesheet file was registered an enqueue correctly. Why the thickbox not showing? please help me!

here is my script use to call the thickbox via an input button

```
var fileInput = '';

    jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function() {
        fileInput = jQuery(this).parent().prev('input.uploadfield');
        //console.log(fileInput);
        formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
        post_id = jQuery('#post_ID').val();
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+post_id+'&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true&width=640&amp;height=105');
        return false;
    });



    window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
    window.send_to_editor = function(html){

        if (fileInput) {
            fileurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');

            fileInput.val(fileurl);

            tb_remove();

        } else {
            window.original_send_to_editor(html);
        }
    };
```

and here is my input button code for upload

```
<input id="" class="uploadfield" type="text" value="" name="" size="50" maxlength="2048">
                                            <div class="upload_buttons">
                                                <input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload">
                                            </div>
```

Comment: I tried to debug the script with firebug. And what I get is the TB_window div not even have anything in it. just like this <div id="TB_window"></div>. but I still don't know how to fix this.

Comment: SOLVED!!! it was because I registered jquery 1.4.2 from ajax googleapis. To fix it I download latest jquery then I registered and enqueue the script as a new admin_jquery. And it work fine. I just don't know why it didn't work with the jquery from ajax googleapis.

Comment: :post your solution as  answer. That may help to others

Comment: I don't know if it is the correct solutions, I just register and enqueque new jquery to the wordpress admin without deregister the jquery from wordpress admin itself to force the wordpres run jquery because it just didn't work when I enqueue the default in-built jquery from wordpress. I hope there is someone have the right answer for this thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the real problem, since I'm using jQuery() in my jquery files instead of $ my code having a conflict with the wordpress built in jquery. so I have to register new jquery with the same name 'jquery' without deregister the wordpress build in jquery.

After I change the sign then I can use the wordpress build in jquery wihout registering new jquery and the thickbox work normally. hope this can help somebody with the same problem. thanks

Comment: I was so dumb at the first time when I think I solved the problem with registering new jquery script. :( but that is the wrong method even though it fix the thickbox but it behaves strange. the thickbox itself has 2 close button when popped out.

Comment: No, you're not dumb. I've tested your js code and it's working: Wordpress native MediaUpload is displayed properly (I do remove post_id from `tb_show`). This is how I enqueue required scripts in the function that generates option page: `wp_register_script('yourjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your.js', array('jquery', 'media-upload', 'thickbox'));` `wp_enqueue_script("yourjs");` `wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');` `wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');` `wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');` You don't need to add jQuery, because it is already included (see `wp-includes/script-loader.php`).